# Filtering array with promise in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
if (filterLabel) {
result = result.filter((r) =>
  (r.labels).map((l) => l.name === filterLabel));}
```

The Error is "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<Label[]>'".

How can I filter this array? filterlabel is a name of a Label like "Test1"

```
export class Task {
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@Column()
name: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@Column()
description: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@CreateDateColumn()
created: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@UpdateDateColumn()
updated: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@ManyToMany(() => Label, (label) => label.tasks)
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@JoinTable()
labels: Promise<Label[]>;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@OneToMany(() => Tracking, (tracking) => tracking.task, {nullable: true})

trackings: Promise<Tracking[]>;
```

}

```
export const getAllTasks = async (req, res) => {
const taskRepository = getRepository(Task);
const tasks = await taskRepository.find(
  {relations: ['trackings', 'labels']});

 const {filterTask, filterDescription, filterLabel} = req.query;
 console.log('1', filterTask, '2', filterDescription, '3', filterLabel, 
 '4');
 let result = [...tasks];

 if (filterTask) {
 result = result.filter((r) => r.name === filterTask);
 }
 if (filterLabel) {
  filter();
 }
 if (filterDescription) {
   result = result.filter((d) => d.description === filterDescription);
 }
  res.status(200).send({data: result});
 };
```

How can i Filter for labels? I dont understand it.
The other filters are right but the label filter is bad because of the promises

Comment: Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a `Promise`, you should `await` it before filtering:

```js
const labels = await r.labels;
result = result.filter((r) =>
  labels.map((l) => l.name === filterLabel));
```

Also, it seems like you actually want `.some` instead of `.map`:

```js
const labels = await r.labels;
result = result.filter((r) =>
  labels.some((l) => l.name === filterLabel));
```

Comment: That doesnt work... when you use await u need a async function and then the filter do not work

Comment: @VLAZ can you help me?

Comment: @Mephisto_08 I've edited the answer so it should work now.